# How to inject context to adapter with hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm using hilt and i want to inject context to an Adapter.

Smth like this

```
class EmployeeAdapter @Inject constructor(@ActivityContext context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
      override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                    Glide
                        .with(context)
                        .load(url)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
                        .into(myImageView)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

is it possible? If yes, please provide an example of the code

Comment: If you are using viewBinding or databinding in your project then get the binding inside viewHolder class and then you can use binding.root.context